# Iframe not loading in modal popup

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I have used a single page HTML page in which I have three div. When I click one of the div modal popups and loads the iframe src. The problem I am facing is iframe is not getting loaded properly when I click the div first time. However in chrome, if I right click and then enter reload frame, my iframe is getting loaded properly. Can anyone say what is the issue I am facing? Why the iframe is not getting loaded properly the first time. I am clueless about this issue. Could anyone please assist me.

My html Code : Posting one div and its corresponding modal popup code

**Div Code :**

```
<div class="bots" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myartModal">
           <font class ="botHeading" ><b> Password Related</b></font><br /> 
              <font class = "botsub">Click here to Change,reset,enroll or unlock your account.</font>
        </div>
```

**Modal Popup**

```
  <div class="container">
      <!--<h2>Basic Modal Example</h2>
       Trigger the modal with a button 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg customModalHeight" role="document">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header customModalHeader">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h3 class="modal-title" ><b>Account Recovery Agent</b></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 z-depth-1-half customIframeHeight">
             <iframe class = "embed-responsive-item" src="http:/xx.xx.xx.xx:4001/"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <!--  <iframe class = "embed-responsive-item" src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4001/"  allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your code, as per asking question guidelines. Hard to answer questions otherwise!

Comment: Added one div code and modal popup code as well. Please assist

Comment: what are you trying to load in the iframe? because this example here: https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/YOyOrG  I made works fine with an Iframe

Comment: I am trying to load a chat window hosted in remote instance.

Comment: did you try my example i linked you but replacing the google map link with your iframe src?